# static resource not loaded in node app.js file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean, ejs

My app.js is as below

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                         //add for Mongo support
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/flapperNews');        //connect to Mongo

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//rout to views
app.use('/', index);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Application Started');
    console.log("Application Started.")
});
app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app;
```

My Directories are as follows
root -> node_modules -> all resource
root -> public -> javascripts -> angularApp.js
I got the following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, your file angularApp.js is available in this url http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angularApp.js

Answer (score 0):

nodejs normally blocks everything outside the public folder (in root) for the client to see

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

this maps the public folder to: /public

so the client isn't able to access any other directory on your system

you need to change the app.use or the folder ;)